# Is there a metric for time taken by AWS-DMS for full load?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch-metrics, aws-dms

I'm using AWS-DMS to migrate **existing data** only from a **Postgres db** as source to **aws-S3** as target. I have created a migration task for this, and I'm able to do the aforementioned.

However, I wanted to know how much time it took for a task to complete. I couldn't find a time completion metric in either the metrics corresponding to the `task` or the metrics corresponding to the `replication-instance`.

How do I find out the time taken for the full load?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the AWS CLI you can try using the [describe-replication-tasks](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/dms/describe-replication-tasks.html) function.

This will provide you with both the Start and Stop times, as well as the time elapsed.

Comment: That works great! Any idea if this is provided in the aws-console too?

Comment: Hmm, it might be in the console, not 100% sure